# Concatenate strings in Less

Tags: css, path, concatenation, less

I think this is not possible, but I thought I ask in case there is a way. The idea is that I have a variable for path to web resource folder:

```
@root: "../img/";
@file: "test.css";
@url: @root@file;

.px {
    background-image: url(@url);
}
```

I get this as a result:

```
.px { background-image: url("../img/" "test.css"); }
```

But, I want the strings to combine into one string like this:

```
.px { background-image: url("../img/test.css"); }
```

Is it possible to concatenate strings together in Less?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Use [Variable Interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation):

```
@url: "@{root}@{file}";
```

Full code:

```
@root: "../img/";
@file: "test.css";

@url: "@{root}@{file}";

.px{ background-image: url(@url); }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is perfect. Now I can make sure that even if the context path changes, there won't be a refactoring nightmare.

Comment: Thanks, i just came across the same problem and missed that in the docs.

Comment: Thanks @Paulpro! I was having an issue with VS Web Compiler add-on, where it was changing my background-image url, and I wasn't too sure how to do concatenation :)

Comment: Just a note for people who might land on this answer but are trying to use it e.g. to combine a numeric variable with a string like `px` or `%`: You can un-quote the string by pre-pending it with a tilde `~`, as such: `width: ~"@{w}px";`

Answer (score 31):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation), you can use string interpolation also with variable and plain strings together:

```
@base-url: "http://assets.fnord.com";
background-image: url("@{base-url}/images/bg.png");
```

Answer (score 12):

I was looking for the same trick for handling images. I used a mixin to answer this:

```
.bg-img(@img-name,@color:"black"){
    @base-path:~"./images/@{color}/";
    background-image: url("@{base-path}@{img-name}");
}
```

Then you can use :

```
.px{
    .bg-img("dot.png");
}
```

or

```
.px{
    .bg-img("dot.png","red");
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! why do you think that the accepted answer is no longer valid? is it outdated? have there been a technology improvement? It's wrong? why yours is better?

Answer (score 9):

For those string-like unit values like `45deg` in `transform: rotate(45deg)` use the `unit(value, suffix)` function. 
Example:

```
// Mixin
.rotate(@deg) {
  @rotation: unit(@deg, deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(@rotation);
  transform: rotate(@rotation);
}

// Usage
.rotate(45);

// Output
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

Comment: Doesn't technically answer the question, but still a useful trick.

Answer (score 7):

Don't know if you're using [less.js](http://lesscss.org/) or lessphp (like in [WP-Less](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-less/) plugin for WordPress) but with lessphp you can "unquote" strings with `~` : http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#string_unquoting

Comment: This works with regular LESS, as well. I do not know if it did in 2012 when this answer was written.

Answer (score -7):

Using Drupal 7. I've used an ordinary plus mark and it's working:

```
@images_path+'bg.png'
```

Comment: Unless he willingly to learn Drupal just for concat strings to use it in LESS/CSS, I think your suggestion is worthless. No offense, I'm just saying.