# Variable Concatenation - using a mixin to dynamically create class name

Tags: css, less, mixins

H I, Working with **[Less](http://lesscss.org/)** and here is what I am hoping :

```
.createClass() {

    @varone:one;
    @vartwo:two;
    @classname: @{varone}_@{vartwo};

    .testClass_@{classname} {
       padding:.5em;
    }

}
.createClass();
```

Things I have tried from a few **[searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256412/concatenate-strings-in-less)** :

```
@classname: '@{varone}_@{vartwo}';
```

But this renders as:

```
    .testClass_'one_two' {
       padding:.5em;
    }
```

And I read about the tilder `~` ( *but might be just for the phpless I found off a search ?* )

```
@classname: ~'@{varone}_@{vartwo}';
```

didn't run.

---

I am running on node , compiling via the **[grunt less contrib](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less)**

---

How do I render a 'unquoted string' in this way / is it possible ?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@classname: ~'@{varone}_@{vartwo}';` (or same with double quotes) is the correct syntax and works in all conformant Less compilers. I.e.:

```
.createClass() {
    @varone: one;
    @vartwo: two;
    @classname: ~'@{varone}_@{vartwo}';

    .testClass_@{classname} {
        padding: .5em;
    }
}

.createClass();
```

Comment: Thanks, @seven-phases-max, I thought I had tried that, but just trying again it worked ( must have had something else amiss) Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh I found it.

http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions

Can use:

`@classname: e(@{varone}_@{vartwo});`

---

The `e(str)` filter does it

---

*Bit more RTFM was needed from me !*

Comment: Yes, `e(...)` is simply an alias function to `~'...'`. (Though the documentation says "CSS escaping, *replaced* with `~"value"` syntax." But of course you can use either of two - it's just a matter of personal preferences).